# Increase the value in the next row by 1 if two values are equal

Tags: r

I got data like this

```
    structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), time = c(1, 2, 2, 5, 
6, 6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

and If for the same ID the value in the next row is equal to the value in the previous row, then increase the value of the duplicate by 1. I want to get this

```
    structure(list(id2 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), time2 = c(1, 2, 3, 
5, 6, 7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: What if there are 3 consecutive rows with the same value?

Comment: I guess will have to repeat the steps after sorting out the two consecutive equal values. But lets says the data only got max two values equal in consecutive rows. How can I deal with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using base R:

```r
ave(df$time, df$time, FUN = function(z) z+cumsum(duplicated(z)))
# [1] 1 2 3 5 6 7
```

(This can be reassigned back into `time`.)

This deals with *2 or more* duplicates, meaning if we instead have another 6th row,

```r
df <- rbind(df, df[6,])
df$time2 <- ave(df$time, df$time, FUN = function(z) z+cumsum(duplicated(z)))
df
#    id time time2
# 1   1    1     1
# 2   1    2     2
# 3   1    2     3
# 4   2    5     5
# 5   2    6     6
# 6   2    6     7
# 61  2    6     8
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `accumulate`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(time2 = accumulate(time, ~if(.x>=.y) .x + 1 else .y))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   id [2]
     id  time time2
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     1
2     1     2     2
3     1     2     3
4     2     5     5
5     2     6     6
6     2     6     7
```

This works even if the group is repeated more than twice.

Comment: These `accumulate()` approach to rolling calculations ir really interesting. It could add some flexibility to my usual `lag()` approach. Nice.

Comment: Is that `purrr::accumulate`?

Comment: @r2evans yes. Still under the impression that OP is using tidyverse

Comment: Nothing in the question (to me) suggests it, perhaps I'm missing something ...

Comment: @r2evans you are right. I must have assumed so by looking at the other answers

Comment: @GuedesBF no need to delete. Its fine. The two answers are different. Your answer was able to solve the specific problem at hand. Next time you will have a better generic answer

Answer (score 0):

If the first data.frame is named `df`, this gives you what you need:

```
df$time[duplicated(df$id) & duplicated(df$time)] <- df$time[duplicated(df$id) & duplicated(df$time)] + 1

df
  id time
1  1    1
2  1    2
3  1    3
4  2    5
5  2    6
6  2    7
```

It finds the rows where both `id` and `time` have been duplicated from the previous row, and adds 1 to `time` in those rows

Comment: While this appears to work here, relying on `duplicated` to deal with grouping operations is prone to a lot of errors. I find this to be more of an Excel-approach, where Excel doesn't give any reasonable windowing, grouping, or merging/joining functionality (of a robust scale, that is).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr`'s `mutate` with `lag`

```
data%>%group_by(id)%>%
        mutate(time=time+cumsum(duplicated(time)))%>%
        ungroup()

# A tibble: 6 x 2
     id  time
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1
2     1     2
3     1     3
4     2     5
5     2     6
6     2     7
```

Comment: This won't work if you have two repeats (three rows, duplicate `time`). For instance, rbind a row with `2` and `6` again and check the output.

Comment: Yes, i eventually understood from Onyambu´s answer that accumulate() is better for these complex rolling operations

Comment: I think it is ok now, @r2evans. `duplicate+cumsum` is tolerant of multiple duplicates and more general, as in your answer